# SVM using Gradient desent - Formula

Tags: machine-learning, octave, svm, gradient-descent

I have been facing a bit difficulty while doing a linear SVM (Support vector machine) using Gradient Descent.

The formula I am using is given below.

[image]

where the first equation is the cost function and the second equation is the theta value for each feature.

c is the control on fitting parameter (Regularization parameter)

alpha decides the rate at which the slope converges.

Somehow When I run the above formula for my data set, My j(theta) keeps on increasing, it never decreases.  I have tried all possible scenarios by changing the value of c and alpha.

If there is any fault at all it might be in the formula, I would be glad if anyone could point it out.

Here Is the Octave Code I am Using:

```
clear all                                                                                                                    
clc

x=[3,1;2,2;1,2;1.5,3;4,1;4,2;4,3;4,5];

y=[1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0];

[m,n]=size(x);
x=[ones(m,1),x];

X=x;

hold off
%. In this step we will plot the graph for the given input data set just to see how is the distribution of the two class.
pos = find(y == 1);  % This will take the postion or array number from y for all the class that has value 1 
neg = find(y == 0);  % Similarly this will take the position or array number from y for all class that has value 0
 % Now we plot the graph column x1 Vs x2 for y=1 and y=0


hold on  
plot(X(pos, 2), X(pos,3), '+');                                                      
plot(X(neg, 2), X(neg, 3), 'o');
axis([min(x(:,2))-2,max(x(:,2))+2, min(x(:,3))-2, max(x(:,3))+2])
xlabel('x1 marks in subject 1')
ylabel('y1 marks in subject 2')
legend('diagonal','failed', 'Pass')
hold off


% feature scaling
%   Now we limit the x1 and x2 we need to leave or skip the first column x0 because they should stay as 1.
% If we dont do feature scalling then the decision line would be opposite.
%mn = mean(x);
%sd = std(x);
%x(:,2) = (x(:,2) - mn(2))./ sd(2);
%x(:,3) = (x(:,3) - mn(3))./ sd(3);




% Algorith for linear SVM
g=inline('1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z))');
theta = zeros(size(x(1,:)))'; 
max_iter=100;
j_theta=zeros(max_iter,1);            % j is a zero matrix that is used to store the theta cost function j(theta)
c=0.1;    
alpha=0.1;
for num_iter =1:max_iter
z=x*theta;
h=g(z);
h
j_theta(num_iter)=c .* (-y'* log(h) - (1 - y)'*log(1-h)) + ((0.5) * (theta'*theta));  % the second term is regularization
%% the above equation computes the cost function

    grad = (c^2) * x' * (h-y);   %% computed the gradient descent 
    reg_exprson= alpha .* (0.5) * (theta'*theta);  %% Computes the regularization term
    theta=theta - (alpha.*grad) - reg_exprson ;  %% Computes the new theta vector for each feature
    theta  

end   

    figure
    plot(0:99, j_theta(1:100), 'b', 'LineWidth', 2)
```

Thanks

Comment: what values of alpha have you tried? the typical reason for this is high value for alpha, and also how do you use gradient descent? is it your own implementation? if so provide us with your code and if not what function do you use and in what language?

Comment: I couldn't find any exact formula for gradient descent with SVM online, So I took the partial derivative of the cost function similar to the one that results in gradient descent for linear regression and logistic regression. I also multiplied a c to the output of the derivative term to balance for not using lambda in regularization term.  I have tried for even for very small values of alpha like 0.3, 0.1 and etc , I am using Octave to develop my code I have attached the piece of code herein my question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you re-implementing this algorithm?

Comment: AdrienNK:  Yes i can use Existing Api's, which will be even more optimized that what i'll achieve. I am trying to write the algorithm to understand how the complete logic works, and also for my learning purpose. I am trying to use gradient descent, newtons algorithms and others to have a end to end knowledge of SVM.